# How do I remove the classes from the pager item-list in Drupal 7?

Tags: theming, paging

I am in a Drupal 7 theme development where we need to over write the pager theme where the class "item-list" needs to be removed.

My current item-list HTML

```
<div class="item-list">
<ul class="pager">
    <li class="pager-first first"><a title="Go to first page" href="/node">« first</a></li>
    <li class="pager-previous"><a title="Go to previous page" href="/node">‹ previous</a></li>
    <li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 1" href="/node">1</a></li>
    <li class="pager-current">2</li>
    <li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 3" href="/node?page=2">3</a></li>
    <li class="pager-next"><a title="Go to next page" href="/node?page=2">next ›</a></li>
    <li class="pager-last last"><a title="Go to last page" href="/node?page=2">last »</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

And I need something like this

```
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">
<ul>
    <li><a title="Go to first page" href="/node">« first</a></li>
    <li><a title="Go to previous page" href="/node">‹ previous</a></li>
    <li><a title="Go to page 1" href="/node">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a title="Go to page 3" href="/node?page=2">3</a></li>
    <li><a title="Go to next page" href="/node?page=2">next ›</a></li>
    <li><a title="Go to last page" href="/node?page=2">last »</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: in your situation you need to override `theme_pager` and `theme_item_list` but `theme_item_list` is used by many functions.

Answer (score 1):

To override the markup of the pager, override the [theme_pager()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) theme function.

However in your case you want to override the class in the item list so for that you need to also override [theme_item_list()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7).

For information on overriding theme functions see the [beginners guide to overriding themeable output](https://drupal.org/node/457740), and for more thorough drupal themeing information see [themeing drupal 6 and 7](https://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7)

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in JQuery.

```
$('ul').removeClass('pager');
$('li').removeClass('pager-first pager-item etc.');
```

The issue with this is that it will run on every page, probably unnecessarily.  If I were you I would find where the class is being applied to the li and ul tags and just remove it from there.

Comment: This is not ideal because it only works for users with js enabled. You're better off fixing the source instead of overriding with js.